# What does もの in the following sentence mean?

Tags: translation, sentence

In the Wikipedia article https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%89%B9%E5%88%A4%E7%9A%84%E6%80%9D%E8%80%83#CITEREF%E9%81%93%E7%94%B02001, it talks about critical thinking and the details that come with it.

In one section, it talks about the guidelines to critical thinking. One guideline in particular says:

> 利用可能なもの、最初の思いついた答えに固執しない。

I think it translates to something like “Available things, do not stick to the initial answer you came up with.”

But I think I am missing something here. Maybe もの has a meaning that connects the first part to the rest of the sentence.

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should parse it like this...

> ［利用可能なもの（や）、 最初の思いついた答え］に固執しない。

So the もの is a noun (物), "thing" "something".

"Do not stick to ［available things and/or the initial answer you came up with］."

Example:

> 使わなくなったもの、要らないものをメルカリで売ろう。

Comment: More concretely, this もの refers to an "idea" or a "solution" you already have.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I've gotten pretty good at parsing Japanese sentences, but some of them definitely had me stumped! But then, I guess Japanese people get stumped over some English sentences, don't they?